# Which is less ordinary? Super- or Extra- ordinary?

Tags: prefixes

I would like to describe something that is even rarer than extraordinary. Does superordinary fit the bill?

Comment: what about singular? Nothing can be rarer than only 1 something being in existence. Doesn't really clear up your super vs. extra dilemma but the only thing more rare than singular would be nonexistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite what you might assume from the individual words, the definitions of *extraordinary* and *superordinary* are actually the **opposite** of *ordinary*.

Something [extraordinary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extraordinary) goes "beyond what is usual, regular, or customary," or is "exceptional to a very marked extent."

Something that is [superordinary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superordinary) is "superior to or in excess of the ordinary."

But to make up a one-off word using *[super-](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/super)something* (scroll down to the prefix entry) would be to say that it was "very something." While [*extra-*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extra)something (scroll down to the prefix entry again) would mean "beyond something" (which is just another way of saying "very").

Nevertheless, as established single words, **superordinary** does not mean "even rarer" than **extraordinary**.

---

Instead, try [**unparalleled**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unparalleled):

> having no parallel; especially : having no equal or match : unique in kind or quality
>
> War crimes of this type are *unparalleled* in history.
>   The new telescope offers an *unparalleled* opportunity to conduct research.
>   Her knowledge of the subject is *unparalleled*.

So, you could say:

> His abilities were not just extraordinary; they were unparalleled.