# Distinction between prefixes 'super-' and 'extra-' in similar contexts

Tags: etymology, synonyms, prefixes, linguistics

From my understanding, both the prefixes `super-` and `extra-` can mean `above` or `beyond`, though a possible distinction could be as follows (from the answer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/452566/which-is-less-ordinary-super-or-extra-ordinary)):

> ...using super-something would be to say that it was "very something." While extra-something would mean "beyond something"...

While a useful dilineation, this isn't always the case for English words. For example, `supernatural` and `superliminal` both seem to adhere to the latter definition, so why use `super-` instead of `extra-`?

There are two aspects of the question that I'd like to be addressed if possible:

1. How is it decided which of these prefixes is more appropriate when
   constructing a new word intended to mean `above/beyond` the root word (or what has the reasoning been in the past)?
2. For existing words with specific cultural connotations, such as `supernatural`, is it appropriate/useful to compose a new word to avoid those connotations, such as `extranatural`, of which the literal meaning is essentially redundant with the original?

Comment: Have you checked an good dictionary?

Comment: What about *hyper*?  That seems even more in vogue these days than *super* or *extra*.

Comment: Extra- sometimes is an intensifier, e.g., extra-pure, extra-fine. So: no rule.

Comment: "Extra" can also mean outside of, like "extrajudicial" doesn't mean "super court" but "outside of court."

Comment: "Extra" comes from Latin.   "Super" comes from Greek, specifically "hyper."  It was common at one point for the Greek H to be transliterated as an S, like "Isaias" getting transliterated as "Isaiah."  The Y in Greek is actually a U in Latin and English.  The reason we have "hyper," too, as well as "upper," is these words got imported from Greek at different times.  Thus, the words "hyper," "super," and "upper" in English all came from the Greek word "ηυπερ" (hyper), while "extra" originated in Latin.

Comment: That's interesting about the Greek derivation, I had thought they were both Latin. It makes more sense that an overlap would result from words having a greater etymological root in either Greek or Latin.

Comment: 'Extra' can mean 'additional' as in "20% extra free" but cannot mean 'greater' as in "extra-sized pack". Conversely 'super' can mean 'greater' as in "super-sized pack" but cannot mean 'additional' as in "20% super free". You do sometimes see them in combination as in "Super-size pack, 20% extra free".